# Remove SQL Server Managed Backup Entry

Tags: sql-server, database-backups

Is there a way to remove a SQL Server Managed Backup entry entirely? (Using Microsoft SQL Server 2017 Enterprise Edition)

We have a database that was renamed (the database name, not the files). Managed Backup configuration was setup again against the new database name. We now have two entries for the same db_guid that show up when we execute:

`select * from managed_backup.fn_backup_db_config (null)`

| db_name | db_guid | ... | is_managed_backup_enabled |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DB1 | e3ff68.. |  | 1 |
| DB2 | e3ff68.. |  | 1 |

In this example DB1 and DB2 are the same database, DB1 was renamed to DB2.

Now trying to disable the backup for DB1 using:

```
EXEC msdb.managed_backup.sp_backup_config_basic   
 @enable_backup = 0,   
 @database_name = 'DB1'
```

We get the error: `SQL Server Managed Backup to Microsoft Azure cannot configure the database, 'DB1', because it either does not exist or is offline.`

We tried creating a new database called DB1, configuring the managed backup to disable the backups, but that's only exacerbated the problem. We now have a new entry in the managed databases with a different db_guid:

| db_name | db_guid | ... | is_managed_backup_enabled |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DB1 | e3ff68.. |  | 1 |
| DB2 | e3ff68.. |  | 1 |
| DB1 | 8ee1ca.. |  | 1 |

Upon dropping the 'new' DB1, it's disappeared from the managed backup.

How do I remove the old duplicate DB1 entry though (without dropping the database which we  don't want to do).

Comment: What harm is the entry causing? Is it creating duplicate backups?

Comment: It’s generating Sql Backup warning emails every 15 minutes. I can’t disable the backup. It’s also nasty having a rogue duplicate entry in there; an avenue for a larger error to be made inadvertently.

Answer (score 0):

```
delete d
FROM msdb.[dbo].[autoadmin_managed_databases] d
where d.drop_date is not null
```